# Is it mathematically correct to write an infinite series in this way?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{x} a_{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$$

Is it mathematically correct to write the following?

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{x} a_{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{lim_{x\to\infty}x} a_{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$$

Comment: There are few "laws" when it comes to notation. As long as it's clear what you mean then you can use whatever notation you like. That being said, this one looks very strange, does not covey any more information than the first ($\lim \sum$) and 'nobody' uses it so I would not write it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\lim_{x \to \infty} x = \infty$, it is correct to say that

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\lim_{x \to \infty} x} a_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $$

because it is a simple substitution. (assuming the infinite sum exists, of course)

---

If you're familiar with the extended natural numbers, you can take the function

$$ g(m) = \sum_{n=1}^m a_n $$

and continuously extended it to a function on the extended natural numbers by setting

$$ g(\infty) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $$

So, in a situation that calls for it (and assuming you are sufficiently familiar with the machinery), you can view the expression

$$ \sum_{n=1}^x a_n $$

as varying continuously in $x$, and

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^x a_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\lim_{x \to \infty} x} a_n $$

as an example of the limit of a continuous function being the function evaluated at the limit.